creating delta tables with parquets from several directories
We are pulling data from a large warehouse and saving it as shown below
table1
  2024-01-01_2024-03-31
  ├── _SUCCESS
  ├── _committed_1849751916443920415
  ├── _started_1849751916443920415
  ├── part-00000-tid-1849751916443920415-b7c7-b932ec8f07df-76362-1.c000.snappy.parquet
  ...
  ├── part-00100-tid-1849751916443920415-b7c7-b932ec8f07df-76364-1.c000.snappy.parquet  
  ...
  2023-10-01_2024-12-31
   ...
  2023-07-01_2024-10-31
  ...
  2011-01-01_2011-03-31

table2
  2024-01-01_2024-03-31
  2023-10-01_2024-12-31
  2023-07-01_2024-10-31
  ...
  2011-01-01_2011-03-31

The different date ranges were pulled in parallel.  After that running
CONVERT TO DELTA parquet. /mnt/azureblobshare/raw_data/.../table1

gives us the required delta tables.
These tables need to be updated monthly - adding the updates within each table directory would obviously work.  Is there a way in which the weekly updates can be created in a separate directory and delta tables be created for each of the tables?
update_2024-04-01_2024-04-08
  table1
    *.parquet
  table2
    *.parquet
update_2024-04-08_2024-04-15
  table1
    *.parquet
  table2
    *.parquet

Can convert to delta be pointed to multiple independent directories?

@ ironv Are you using Azure databricks?

@DileeprajnarayanThumula yes!

I have tried the below approach:
I have created some sample data like below for Table 1 and Table 2, and saved the data as Parquet.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os
dilip_table1_data = [
    (1, 'John', 90),
    (2, 'Jane', 85),
    (3, 'Mark', 95),
    (4, 'Emily', 88)
]
dilip_df_table1 = spark.createDataFrame(dilip_table1_data, ["id", "name", "score"])
dilip_df_table1.write.parquet("/FileStore/tables/RAW/dilip/table1/2024-01-01_2024-03-31/part-00000.parquet")
dilip_table2_data = [
    (1, 'Tom', 78),
    (2, 'Lisa', 92),
    (3, 'Mike', 80),
    (4, 'Sarah', 87)
]
dilip_df_table2 = spark.createDataFrame(dilip_table2_data, ["id", "name", "score"])
dilip_df_table2.write.parquet("/FileStore/tables/RAW/dilip/table2/2024-01-01_2024-03-31/part-00000.parquet")

Next, I have updated Table 1 and Table 2.
update_1_dilip_table1_data = [
    (5, 'Oliver', 92),
    (6, 'Emma', 87)
]
dilip_df_update_1_table1 = spark.createDataFrame(update_1_dilip_table1_data, ["id", "name", "score"])
update_1_table1_dir = "/FileStore/tables/RAW/dilip/new/update_2024-04-01_2024-04-08/table1"
os.makedirs(update_1_table1_dir, exist_ok=True)
dilip_df_update_1_table1.write.parquet(f"{update_1_table1_dir}/part-00000.parquet")
spark.sql(f"CONVERT TO DELTA parquet.`{update_1_table1_dir}`")

update_1_dilip_table2_data = [
    (5, 'Olivia', 85),
    (6, 'Daniel', 90)
]
dilip_df_update_1_table2 = spark.createDataFrame(update_1_dilip_table2_data, ["id", "name", "score"])
update_1_table2_dir = "/FileStore/tables/RAW/dilip/new/update_2024-04-01_2024-04-08/table2"
os.makedirs(update_1_table2_dir, exist_ok=True)
dilip_df_update_1_table2.write.parquet(f"{update_1_table2_dir}/part-00000.parquet")
spark.sql(f"CONVERT TO DELTA parquet.`{update_1_table2_dir}`")

In the above code, I have created the update directory, saved the update data as Parquet, and converted the update directory to Delta.
Results:
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/FileStore/tables/RAW/dilip/new/update_2024-04-01_2024-04-08/table2")
df.show()

+---+------+-----+
| id|  name|score|
+---+------+-----+
|  5|Olivia|   85|
|  6|Daniel|   90|
+---+------+-----+

df1 = spark.read.format("delta").load("/FileStore/tables/RAW/dilip/new/update_2024-04-01_2024-04-08/table1")
df1.show()

+---+------+-----+
| id|  name|score|
+---+------+-----+
|  5|Oliver|   92|
|  6|  Emma|   87|
+---+------+-----+


once the updates are done, we would like the table to show all the rows.  In your examples, tables 1&2 would each have 6rows

delta_table = delta_table 
.merge(update_data, "id") 
.whenMatchedUpdateAll() 
.whenNotMatchedInsertAll() 
.execute()
You  can read the existing and updated table data Merge the updated data with the existing Delta table and show the results
